# Config file for running service in Kubernetes doesn't work well

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a config file named "pod.yaml" for making a pod like bellow:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
    containers:
      - name: comet-app
        image: gcr.io/my-project/my-app:v2
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000`

and a config file named "service.yaml" for running a service in that "myapp" pod.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    run: myapp`

When I run

```
 kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
 kubectl apply -f service.yaml
```

The 'myapp' service is created but I couldn't access my website by the internal ip and it returned ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

`NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.xx.xxx.1     <none>           443/TCP        11d
myapp        LoadBalancer   10.xx.xxx.133   35.xxx.xx.172    80:30273/TCP   3s`

But when I deleted that service and re-run by exposing a service with bellow command, everything worked well and I could access to my website by the external-ip.

```
 kubectl expose pod myapp  --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=5000
```

Could anyone explain it for me and tell me what is wrong in my service.yaml?

Comment: What does _I couldn't access my website by the internal ip_ mean?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. gcr.io/my-project/my-app:v2 is a docker image of my website. if everything going well, when I access to the EXTERNAL-IP 35.xxx.xx.172 in service list, my website will be showed.

Comment: that is, as its heading implies, the _external IP_ of your `Service`. Ok, so what does "couldn't access" mean: connection refused, connection timed out, a 404 page, a 500 page, a 200 but blank page?

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to edit my question. It means "connection timed out".

Comment: Can you try the following: in `service.yaml` change `run: myapp` to `app: myapp`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael Hausenblas. It works!!!

Comment: OK @QuocLap glad to learn this. I will put this down as the answer then, which you can accept then so that others also benefit from it.

Comment: Ok, I'm done accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `service.yaml` is that the selector is wrong. [How it works](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) is that a service by default routes traffic to pods with a certain label. Your pod has the label `app: myapp` whereas in the service your selector is `run: myapp`. So, changing `service.yaml` to the following should solve the issue:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: myapp
```